# How can a grad student get funding without doing research?

Tags: graduate-school, funding

I am a 1<sup>st</sup>-year graduate student at University of Oregon, and I am trying to find funding for my education.

The problem I am running into is finding funds that don't require research. My career path doesn't involve deep research projects and it seems the requirement for a majority of scholarships require students doing research.

Any tips?

Comment: What is your field?  Teaching assistantships are a major source of funding for grad students in many fields.  Also, what type of graduate degree are you pursuing (masters / PhD / ???)

Comment: It wouldn't kill you to help out with a research project even if you don't plan to pursue a research path later on.  Don't worry.  You can likely find a position where you can be a lackey and cheerfully do some grunt work for someone's project.

Comment: All openings for graduate employee positions (which provide a salary, a tuition waiver, and health insurance benefits) at the UO are posted here: https://gradschool.uoregon.edu/gtf-openings 
But I recommend talking to your department as well to see what the prospects of getting a TA position are.

Answer (score 2):

Teaching assistantships (TA-ships) should be your savior. I am on the doctoral committee of a graduate student in our department who wants to teach at liberal arts colleges post degree and therefore wants to gain as much teaching experience as possible.

She is still doing research and getting published in top conferences - just not at the scale at which other students (who want to focus primarily on research) are.

Another lesser seen but useful mode of funding is through what most schools call graduate assistantships (GAs). Here, you will be assisting in academic administration or other managerial responsibilities closely associated with research activities but not actual research itself.

I encourage you to explore those options. Departments usually have a limited number of these options.